# create custom view with ImageView, Asynctask not working

Tags: java, android, image, android-asynctask

I want to add Views programmatically to a ViewFlipper :

```
flipper.addView(anEpisode(name, null, description), i);
```

my method is :

```
public View anEpisode(String n, String i, String d){
    View v;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.episodedescription, null);

    TextView nameOfEpisode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.episodedescriptionname);
    ImageView imageOfEpisode = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.episodedescriptionimage);
    TextView descriptionOfEpisode = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.episodedescriptiondescription);

    nameOfEpisode.setText(n);
    descriptionOfEpisode.setText(d);
    createUrlImage(imageOfEpisode, i);

    return v;
}
```

and the createUrlImage is :

```
private class CreateImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
    ImageView image;
    public CreateImage(ImageView img) {
        image = img;
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... urls) {
        InputStream is;
        Drawable d = null ;
        try {
            is = (InputStream)new URL(urls[0]).getContent();
            d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "Image");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return d;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Drawable d) {
        image.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }
}
public void createUrlImage(ImageView img, String url){
    new CreateImage(img).execute(url);
}
```

The thing is : it doesn't display image at all so i don't know what to do.

Comment: You could trace your code and see what the computer does.

Comment: How can i do that ? I just know how to use the debuger.

Comment: ResourceType : Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f.... there is this line for all the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with drawable bounds.  Set the bounds in `onPostExecute()` method.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Drawable d) {
    d.setBounds (0, 0, getIntrinsicWidth(), getIntrinsicHeight());
    image.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
```

Comment: what is getIntrinsicWidth, and getIntrinsicHeight ?

Comment: Ow ok, it was a method from drawable, but it doesn't work, and now it's slowing the app.

Comment: yes, method from drawable. Missed that. Try giving a static value in place of `getIntrinsicWidth` and `getIntrinsicHeight`. Like `d.setBounds (0, 0, 100, 100);` or what ever you think will not exceed the real height and width.

Comment: Okay, thank you, it's working with Debug and my Phone but not with the emulator, no big deal. It's working with getIntrinsicWidth() and getIntrinsicHeight(), it's just that i had createUrlImage(imageOfEpisode, i) in commentary.

Comment: I can't give you the bounty prize yet but i'll do it when i can.